# Form Where User Enters Multiple Fields to Run a Report, Leave Blank to Show All

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a working form/query/report where the user enters the Start Date, End Date, and Type, which will then run a report of Deposits based on those parameters.

The user enters the info on the form (called 'TypeAndDateSelectDeposit'):

[image]

A report is then generated using this query:
[image]

I want the user to be able to either select an 'All Types' option, or just leave Type blank, and have all types show on the report.

How do I make this happen?  At this point, if Type is left blank, then nothing shows on the report, because every Deposit has to have a type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user selects a value other than *'All Types'*, you want the rows which match that value.

But if the user selects *'All Types'* or leaves the combo blank, you don't want any filtering based on *DepositType*.

You can write those conditions into your query's `WHERE` clause ...

```sql
WHERE
    [put your date selection criteria here]
    AND
    (
           DepositType = Forms!TypeAndDateSelectDeposit!Type
        OR Forms!TypeAndDateSelectDeposit!Type = 'All Types'
        OR Forms!TypeAndDateSelectDeposit!Type Is Null
    )
```

Comment: This is perfect!  I decided not to add an 'All Types' option, so I took that line of code out and just added an instruction to the user to leave Type blank to select all.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a Select All option to the dropdown list.

If the Combo box is populated by the query, "SELECT Column1, Column2 from Table1", then change it to:

```
SELECT Column1, Column2 from Table1 UNION SELECT "*", "<ALL>" from Table1
```

Then, the query that's behind your report will essentially filter by

```
DepositType = *
```

which should pull all records.